# Prove $\sqrt s$ exists by the Intermediate Value Thorem?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm pretty sure the process is right, but I'm not sure if I've validly presented the proof. Here is what I wrote:

Suppose that $s > 0$ and consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[a,b]$ where $a=0$ and $b=s+(1/2)$. Thus, $f(a) = f(0) = 0$ and $f(b) = f(s+(1/2)) = s^2 + s + (1/4)$. Because $s>0$,

$0<s<s^2+s+(1/4)$,

meaning $f(a) < s < f(b)$. Therefore, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists a $c$ in $(0, s + (1/2))$ such that $f(c) = s$. Because $f(c) = c^2$, plugging in a value of $\sqrt s$ for $c$ yields $f$($\sqrt s$) = $s$. Therefore, $c = \sqrt s $ exists.

Is this thorough enough?

Comment: Looks good to me. ((EDIT:)) Well, maybe not ... Your last sentence (which I only glanced at) is wrong; Bananach has the fix: $c^2=f(c)=s$, and $c\ge 0$, so $c=\sqrt s$ by definition (since $c$ exists).

Comment: Except for the end. Why would you "plugin a value of $\sqrt{s}$" before having shown $\sqrt{s}$ exists? The fact that  $c^2=f(c)=s$ is the definition of the square root of $s$, thus you are already done at the point where you find $c$.

Comment: Except that the last half sentence seems to make less sense: "plugging in a value of $\sqrt s$" sounds like you *assume* the existence of $\sqrt s$ at that point. On the contrary. $\sqrt s$ is (probably) defined as *the unique non-negative number the square of which is $s$*. So I'd end with something like "As $c\ge 0$ and $c^2=f(c)=s$, $c$ matches the definition of square root of $s$, i.e., $\sqrt s$ exists (and equals $c$)"